# How do you freeze the scene an Interstitial iAd is presented over?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad

Hey all so I finally got my interstitial iAd's working but I've run into a slight problem. When the user hits replay in my game, it instantly loads my interstitial iAd before my InstructionScene is loaded, but if I tap the iAd, it loads my GameScene. On my InstructionScene, you simply tap to start when you're ready to play. So while the iAd is being shown, how do I pause the InstructionScene so that when the user taps the ad it doesn't trigger the game to begin?

**Code in my GameOver scene**

```
func interstitialAdChecker(){
    var randomAd = Int(arc4random() % 3)
    println(randomAd)

    if randomAd == 1 {
        interstitialBool = true
    }
}

func interstitialAd(){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("showInterstitialAdsID", object: nil)
}
```

This code gets called when the user hits replay:

```
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.replayButton {
            if interstitialBool == true {
                interstitialAd()
            }

            var scene = InstructionScene(size: self.size)
            let skView = view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        }
     }
```

**Code in my InstructionScene**

In my InstructionScene i have this code set up for switching scenes to the PlayScene:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {    
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
        let skView = view as SKView!
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

Basically the user just has to touch the screen and it switches the scene to my PlayScene.

Answer (score 0):

You can pause the scene by using `skView.paused = true` and play the scene again by using `skView.paused = false`.

When the property is set to true, the content is fixed and there is no physics simulation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013031-CH1-SW8

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where would you implement the skView.pause = true? In an interstitial function in the view controller? The scene after the condition is met?

Comment: I would put it in the method that displays the ad. I had a type, it is `skView.paused = true`. I will fix the answer.